# Meteor upgrade issue: forgotPwd route configured but showForgotPasswordLink set to false

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, telescope

I am facing issue with my meteor project after upgrading 1.0 to 1.2.1. The issue says `forgotPwd route configured but showForgotPasswordLink set to false`. But the value of showForgotPasswordLink is true itself when i checked in `AccountsTemplates.configure(packages\telescope-core\lib\config.js)`.

Anybody have idea on this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have the following code in your [`Telescope/packages/telescope-core/lib/config.js`](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/blob/c8363840123ddced10407a1e04c696663c8622c7/packages/telescope-core/lib/config.js) file:

```
//Routes
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signIn');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signUp', {
  path: '/register'
});
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('forgotPwd');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('resetPwd');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('changePwd');
//AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('enrollAccount');
//AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('verifyEmail');


// Options
AccountsTemplates.configure({
    enablePasswordChange: true,
    showForgotPasswordLink: true,
    confirmPassword: false,
    overrideLoginErrors: true,
    lowercaseUsername: true,

    negativeFeedback: false,
    positiveFeedback: false,
    negativeValidation: true,
    positiveValidation: true
});
```

You receive the error `forgotPwd route configured but showForgotPasswordLink set to false` because the execution order is wrong.

From the [Iron Router add-on for User Accounts documentation](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/iron-routing#routes):

> NOTE: some routes need other useraccounts' regular options to be set
>   in advance. Please make sure to have your calls to
>   AccountsTemplates.configureRoute be executed after your calls to the
>   regular AccountsTemplates.configure

As a result, you need to place your `AccountsTemplates.configureRoute` after `AccountsTemplates.configure`.

```js
// Options
AccountsTemplates.configure({
  enablePasswordChange: true,
  showForgotPasswordLink: true,
  confirmPassword: false,
  overrideLoginErrors: true,
  lowercaseUsername: true,

  negativeFeedback: false,
  positiveFeedback: false,
  negativeValidation: true,
  positiveValidation: true
});

//Routes
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signIn');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signUp', {
  path: '/register'
});
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('forgotPwd');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('resetPwd');
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('changePwd');
//AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('enrollAccount');
//AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('verifyEmail');
```